# Rake aborted, and does not know how to build task 'mayapy -m compileall src\python', how to trace this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I get the error "Don't know how to build task 'mapapy -m compileall". I'm still new to ruby, so just wanted an idea of how to resolve this?

```
mayapy -m compileall src\python
rake aborted!

Command failed with status (127): [mayapy -m compileall src\python...]
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `sh'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/PycharmProjects/robotanimator/Rakefile:43:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Ruby23-x64/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/Ruby23-x64/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
```

`This is the rake file`

```
`require 'rake/clean'`    
`require 'fileutils'`    
`require 'kramdown'`    
`require 'date'`    
`require 'erb'`    

`RELEASE = 'Maya_' + ENV["maya_version"]`    
`if ENV["maya_version"] == '2015'`    
    `RELEASE = RELEASE + '-x64'`    
`end`    

`INNO_CC = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Inno Setup 5/Compil32.exe'`    
`INNO_SCRIPT = 'setup/RobotAnimator.iss'`      
`INNO_SCRIPT_ERB = "#{INNO_SCRIPT}.erb"`  
`INSTALLER = "setup/#{APP_ID}-#{APP_TYPE}_#{CLIENT}_#{VERSION}b#{BUILD_ID}_#{RELEASE}.exe"`  

`DOCSRC = FileList['src/markdown/*.md']`  
`DOCS = DOCSRC.pathmap('docs/%n.html')`  

`CLEAN.include('**/*.pyc', '**/*.pyo', '**/*.iss', 'docs/*')`  

`task :default => :install`  

`desc 'Compile the InnoSetup installer script and run the installer'`  
`task :install => [:installer] do`  
  `sh INSTALLER`  
`end`  

`desc 'Compile the InnoSetup installer script'`  
`task :installer => [:compile, :doc, :inno_script] do
  sh %Q{"#{INNO_CC}" /cc "#{INNO_SCRIPT}"}`  
`end`
```

`task :compile do`
      `sh 'mayapy -m compileall src\\python'`
    `end`

```
`desc 'Generate the HTML documentation'
task :doc => ['docs', 'docs/index.html'] + DOCS`  

`task :inno_script do
  erb_build INNO_SCRIPT, INNO_SCRIPT_ERB
 end`  

`file 'docs/index.html' => 'src/html/index.html' do |t|
  source = t.prerequisites.first
  puts "#{source} >> #{t.name}"
  FileUtils.cp(source, t.name)
end`  

`rule '.html' => [-> n { n.pathmap('src/markdown/%n.md') }] do |t|
  puts "#{t.source} >> #{t.name}"
  doc = Kramdown::Document.new(File.read(t.source))
  File.open(t.name, 'w') {|f| f.puts doc.to_html }
end`  

`directory 'docs'`  

`def erb_build(dest, src)
  b = binding
  IO.write(dest, ERB.new(IO.read(src)).result(b))
end`
```

So currently I'm trying to compile the rake task - INNO_CC = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Inno Setup 5/Compil32.exe'

Comment: could you please share your rake task

Comment: i was to figure out the python error mayapy -m compileall src\python it was due to not proper setup of the external interpreter which was mayapy - the maya installation path.